# Create a login check with sql sever 2008 function

Tags: php, sql-server, function

i am trying to code a login check with sql server 2008 function and also
i want to run this function on php .
The returned variable will be a BIT so if the user exists i will get a 1 or 
a 0 if it does not. I can't get it work , i am new to sql server datbase if someone knows a solution please answer.

My code so far :

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.checklogin (@username varchar, @password varchar )
RETURNS bit
AS
   BEGIN
       Declare @checked bit

    select   @checked = CAST(
   CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.user where dbo.user.username=@username and dbo.user.password=@password THEN 1 
   ELSE 0 )

       RETURN @checked
  END
  GO
```

Thanks for reading :) !

Comment: You really need to change how you handle passwords. They should hashed and salted instead of stored in plain text. It would be helpful if you included error messages. That would have made it easier to spot that you are missing the END for your case expression. And you are also missing the second half your cast.

Comment: this is just a prototype i will make necessary changes in advance. Thanks for commenting.  How should  i end the case expression ?

Comment: this is the error i get :
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure checklogin, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.

Comment: The basic format for a case expression "case when [condition] then [result] end"

Comment: There are just so many syntax errors in there it is hard to pinpoint them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really needs a complete rethinking because you need to store hashed and salted passwords instead of plain text. I took the liberty of turning this scalar function into an inline table valued function. It is far more flexible and will perform better. I hope you have a unique constraint on username in your table. but when casting to a bit any value >= 1 will become 1.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.checklogin (@username varchar, @password varchar )
RETURNS table as return
    select CAST(count(*) as bit) as UserFound
    FROM dbo.user 
    where dbo.user.username = @username 
        and dbo.user.password = @password
```

Treating this purely academically here is the proper syntax for the methodology you were trying to write.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.checklogin (@username varchar, @password varchar )
RETURNS bit
AS
   BEGIN
       Declare @checked bit

        select @checked = CAST(
        CASE WHEN EXISTS
        (
            SELECT * 
            FROM dbo.[user] u 
            where u.username = @username 
                and u.password = @password
        ) THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 END as bit)

       RETURN @checked
  END
```

Comment: This look nice , thanks Sean ! Now the problem is how do i store the bit value into a php variable ? Beacause it looks like this is going to return an array , or am i wrong?

Comment: It will return a table. You could use the edit where I fixed up your code. I have no idea to put this into a php variable. I can't even spell php, let alone know anything about it.

Comment: I would STRONGLY recommend you look at storing your passwords correctly. Plain text just isn't good enough these days.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :) , i use php functions to encrypt the password before it is stored in the database. like md5 or others.

Comment: md5 is pretty weak as there have been proven cracks for it. You would be better suited using a salted hash but it sounds like you are familiar with that process. Hope you are able to use this. Cheers.